# How to insert the value of DateButton into a table through sql in java

Tags: java

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Buses ( RegNo,BusNo, Model, Capacity, DatePurchased,InsuranceStatus,DateInsured,ExpiryDate) VALUES ('"
        + txtRegNo.getText() + "', '"
        + txtBusNo.getText() + "', '"
        + txtModel.getText() + "', '"
        + txtCapacity.getText() + "', '"
        + date_bought.getText() + "', '"
        + txtIStatus.getText() + "', '"
        + date_ins.getText() + "', '"
        + date_expiry.getText() + "')";
```

Comment: read about PreparedStatement please

Comment: What issue are you having? What have you tried so far to solve it? Please share your attempts, and tell us what exactly doesn't work. Also, if you get any error attach the full stack trace.

Comment: What is the Java class of `DateButton`? What is the column type of the database field you want to store its value in?